# python3 not installed from /etc/apk/world

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

I have created my own `lbu` for a customized USB bootable installation. The `apkovl` file contains the apk cache.

Everything works as expected. All packages, but `python3`, from `/etc/apk/world` are installed as Alpine boots from the USB media.

Here the contents

```
acct
alpine-base
chrony
e2fsprogs
linux-vanilla
openssh
openssl
python3
syslinux
vim
```

Right after booting, `python3` is not found. `Vim` is installed and works. If I do an `apk fix`, `python3` gets installed from the local cache and works.

The USB media booted Alpine does not have network connection, and should not. As `apk fix` installs from the local cache it seems to work generally.

I have no logs that point me to any apk issue during boot.

Any idea what could go wrong? How to debug the problem?

Comment: The apkovl does not contain apk cache. 
What version of alpine are you running?
What's the content of /etc/apk/repositories?

Please run setup-apkcache first.
Then run : 
apk update && apk add python3 && apk cache sync.